# Show path with arrows in a matrix

Tags: output-formatting, graphs-and-networks

I have a matrix, for example, 5x5 matrix `Partition[Range[25], 5]`. And I am given a list, for example:

```
 {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {4, 2}, 
 {3, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, 
 {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}
```

and I need to trace the path from the element in `(1,1)` to `(2, 1)`, and then from `(2, 1)` to `(3, 1)`, etc., from `(4, 5)` to `(5, 5)` and end there.

How can I draw this graphically with an arrow indicating each of the transition?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  Is it an assignment?  The exact same question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812371/how-to-trace-a-path-graphically-in-a-matrix-in-mathematica

Comment: @Szabolcs: no it is not assignment. It is different from that question; here, I need arrows.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you going to use this for?

Comment: just some visualization. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mathematica's `Graph` related functionality is pretty great. You can easily style vertexes, edges and their labels, apply interesting functions. For small increase in code sophistication you gain quite a bit of advantage. Your data:

```
poli = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {4, 2}, {3, 
    2}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {5, 
    4}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}};
```

**A simple solution** with still quite wide styling options I think would be this

```
arrow[coord_, e_] := Style[Arrow[coord], Red, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[0.06]]

pg = PathGraph[Range[19], VertexCoordinates -> poli, 
EdgeShapeFunction -> arrow, ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> .2];

gg = GridGraph[{5, 5}, EdgeStyle -> Dashed, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> .2];

Overlay[{gg, pg}]
```

[image]

**The rest** is some more elaborate exploratory fun with graphs.

We'll use `GridGraph` again but instead of `PathGraph` we'll use `GraphHighlight` option. `GridGraph` has its own 1D node index system (see indexes above), not 2D indexes as in matrix. So we have to remap the indexes.

```
vertex = (5 (#[[1]] - 1) + #[[2]]) & /@ poli;

edge = ( #[[1]] \[UndirectedEdge] #[[2]]) & /@ Partition[vertex, 2, 1];
```

To add correct labels:

```
lab = MapThread[Rule[#1, ToString@#2] &, {vertex, poli}];

GridGraph[{5, 5}, EdgeStyle -> Dashed, GraphHighlight -> edge, 
 VertexLabels -> lab, PlotRangePadding -> .3]
```

[image]

If you want arrows there are many ways around, especially depending on how you choose the path. Quick cooking gives something like this:

```
arr[coord_, e_] := 
 Style[Arrow[
   If[Positive[(e)[[2]] - (e)[[1]]], Identity[coord], 
    Reverse[coord]]], Red, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[0.06]]

GridGraph[{5, 5}, EdgeStyle -> Dashed, GraphHighlight -> edge, 
 VertexLabels -> lab, PlotRangePadding -> .5, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (# -> arr & /@ edge)]
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error `GridGraph::optx: "Unknown option EdgeStyle->Dashing[{Small,Small}] in "`. What version of Mma are you using? Thanks!

Comment: @QiangLi I use V8.0.4 - just updated the code. It works for me.

Comment: It is very strange here. I can sometimes get the command `GridGraph[{5, 5}, VertexSize -> Small, 
 GraphHighlight -> {3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2}]` executed, but not other times. What is going on here?

Comment: Looks like I cannot do `GridGraph[{5, 5}, VertexSize -> Small, 
 GraphHighlight -> {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}]` because the last 6 is larger than the dimension 5.

Comment: I see. Because there is no edge between 4 and 6 above. No, I am using V8.0.0.

Comment: If a post gets edited more than 10 times, it becomes community wiki and it is not possible to earn reputation from it any more.  (Just mentioning in case you didn't know --- I learned the hard way too)

Answer (score 12):

Make a graphics where you put at each position `{i,j}` the entries of your matrix. The only thing left to do is to transform your path positions from the form `{p1,p2,...}` into `{{p1,p2},{p2,p3},...}`, which can easily done with `Partition`. Then you can map `Arrow` over this list and have your result

```
m = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 5}]; 
path = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {4, 2}, 
       {3, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, 
       {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}}; 
Graphics[{Table[Text[Style[m[[j, i]], Blue, 18], {i, -j}], 
       {i, 5}, {j, 5}], Opacity[0.5], Red, 
     Arrow /@ Partition[({1, -1}*#1 & ) /@ path, 2, 1]}]
```

*note* that you have to plot your matrix entries and the path points upside down to make the entry `{1,1}` appear at the top.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
a = Partition[Range@25, 5];

path = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {4, 2}, {3, 
    2}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {5, 
    4}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}};

Graphics[{
  Text[#2, #] & @@@ Most@ArrayRules[a],
  Arrow[path]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After seeing other answers I suppose you did intend different coordinates:

```
Graphics[{
  Text[#2, {1, -1} Reverse@#] & @@@ Most@ArrayRules[a],
  Arrow[{1, -1} # & /@ path]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Let's define the matrix and path first:

```
matrix = Partition[Range[25], 5];

path = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {4, 2}, {3, 
    2}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {5, 
    4}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}};
```

Then this is my preferred solution:

```
radius = 0.25;
Graphics[
 {MapIndexed[{Circle[#2, radius], Text[#, #2]} &, matrix, {2}],
  Arrow[#, radius] & /@ Partition[path, 2, 1]},

 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[1/20]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can easily style the arrows and `Disk`s or `Circle`s to your liking.  The key to making this look good was the second argument of `Arrow` which makes it possible to easily offset the beginning and endpoints, so they don't overlap the disks.